# Getting error while calling Webservices from C# console Application

Tags: c#, console

> I have facing issue on string FindCardMetaData(), it shows Expected;
>   or = (Cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using KanbanAddIn.KanbanMetadataService;

namespace KanbanAddIn
{
   public class KanbanCard
     {
          static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               const string USER_ID = "niket";
               KanbanMetadataService.iformPortTypeClient MetadataClient = new iformPortTypeClient("iformServiceSOAP11port");
                  string FindCardMetaData()
                    {
                         MetadataClient.getCardMetadata(new getCardMetadata_Input()
                            {
                                 userLoginId = USER_ID,
                                 cardType = "KanbanDefect"
                            });
                              return "";
                     }         
            }                   
     }
}
```

Error Screen shots:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's just syntax mistake, you cannot declare method inside another method. Here is compiler friendly code:

```
public class KanbanCard
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string USER_ID = "niket";
        var cardMetadata = FindCardMetaData(USER_ID);

    }

    static KanbanAddIn.KanbanMetadataService.getCardMetadata_Response FindCardMetaData(string userId)
    {
        KanbanMetadataService.iformPortTypeClient MetadataClient = new iformPortTypeClient("iformServiceSOAP11port");
        return MetadataClient.getCardMetadata(new getCardMetadata_Input()
        {
            userLoginId = userId,
            cardType = "KanbanDefect"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but in return is blank nothing in return... it should be shown xml format response.

Comment: @NiketPatil it seems something is wrong with your webservice or request. We have just made the code compile, but we don't know how to work with webservice

Comment: Okay Thanks ......but One think when I call webservices from SOAPUI it response will be getting correctly it seems there is not issue in WebSevices code where as in C# code it getting returning NULL.

Comment: @NiketPatil I've updated my answer. `FindCardMetaData` was always returning empty string. Now it returns response.

Comment: No Not works!. Show Error : Can not implicitly convert type 'KanbanAddIn.KanbanMetadataService.getCardMetadata_Response' to 'string'

Comment: @NiketPatil see updated answer. Return type of the method changed to `KanbanAddIn.KanbanMetadataService.getCardMetadata_Response`

Comment: Yes, I have check that you have changes in this: 
  return MetadataClient.getCardMetadata(new getCardMetadata_Input()

But when execute the code it seems like shows error:
Can not implicitly convert type 'KanbanAddIn.KanbanMetadataService.getCardMetadata_Response' to 'string'

Comment: @NiketPatil I also changed method signature. See after keyword `static`

Comment: Ok that is work but I tired for that return value should be display in Locals C# console, but not yet it

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a function here like this:

```
 string FindCardMetaData()
 {
      MetadataClient.getCardMetadata(new getCardMetadata_Input()
      {
            userLoginId = USER_ID,
            cardType = "KanbanDefect"
      });
      return "";
 }
```

Put it somewhere else in the class body.